# Running JavaScript within a Service in Android

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview, android-service, rhino

I have business logic that is written in JavaScript, this code is shared with other non-android apps.

What is the best way to use the functions in this piece of JavaScript from within a Service in Android.

AFAIK, there are 2 options?

- V8 that is built into the standard WebView and superfast, no extra apk bloat.
- Rhino, which is tricky to get going on Android?

Focusing on V8/Webview, when I attempt to access the WebView, with any function, I get;

```
All WebView methods must be called on the UI thread. Future versions of WebView may not support use on other threads.
```

The warning being noted, it doesn't even work now. When I set the webviewclient up, I get nothing after loading an URL.

My question is in 3 parts;

1) Has anyone had any success with running javascript in a webview without a UI thread?

2) How do I get results from the functions inside the javascript, does the webview interface "addJavascriptInterface " support loading a parameter and sending it back to the java?

3) If either of the above are impossible.. I guess I'll go get Rhino, any tips would be appreciated, I've only seen a few blogs complaining of issues with regards to getting it going on Android and wondering if there is a "go to" version for android maintained somewhere.

Comment: Why was this downvoted. I put a lot of effort to figuring this out in the end and I'm sure a lot of developers out there are interested in using a scripted language in Android...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Couldn't find anything with regards to V8 from deep down in a service.

Ended up using Rhino, however a word of warning to anyone following down my footsteps, it's incredibly slow.

Just grab the jar from the official latest distribution of Rhino from
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Rhino/Download_Rhino?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=RhinoDownload

js.jar is what you need in the zip. js-14 is a bigger java 1.4 compatible version you don't need.

Integration was a snap just chuck the jar into your libs folder.

Below is me scraping a webpage using javascript (turning the data into better formatted json). With the parse.js script I made coming from the assets folder.

Rhino doesn't come with DOM, and env.js crashes out with stackoverflow errors. Overall, I'd say this solution is slow and not well supported...

```
public static void sync(Context context, ){
    String url = BASE_URL;

    String html = Utils.inputStreamToString(Utils.getHTTPStream(url));

    timeList.add(System.currentTimeMillis());

    if(html == null){
        Utils.logw("Could not get board list.");
        return;
    }

    String parsingCode = null;
    try {
        parsingCode = Utils.inputStreamToString(context.getAssets().open("parse.js"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Utils.logw("Could not get board parser js");
        return;
    }

    // Create an execution environment.
    org.mozilla.javascript.Context cx = org.mozilla.javascript.Context.enter();

    // Turn compilation off.
    cx.setOptimizationLevel(-1);

    try {
        // Initialize a variable scope with bindnings for
        // standard objects (Object, Function, etc.)
        Scriptable scope = cx.initStandardObjects();

        ScriptableObject.putProperty(
                scope, "html", org.mozilla.javascript.Context.javaToJS(html, scope));

        //load up the function
        cx.evaluateString(scope, parsingCode,"parseFunction", 1 , null);

        // Evaluate the script.
        Object result = cx.evaluateString(scope, "myFunction()", "doit:", 1, null);

        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result.toString());
```

Comment: Hi, I'm curious how slow it is. Can you share some numeric results you got? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Extreme, i was using it to parse html. with something that would take native code, 1 to 2 seconds would take 45 seconds for rhino.

Comment: @yhpark it would be great if you could upvote the question so that other people don't think this is an invalid question. I was the victim of serial downvoting and I think if this question and answer was useful, it shouldn't sit with a negative :)

Comment: I have similar html parsing situation just like you! I'm not working on it right now but when I do, I'll probably share my results here. Thanks